# How to get html5 canvas, kineticjs image rotate working in IE9?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, kineticjs

We have a website that used HTML5 canvas and KineticJS to scale and resize and rotate an image on top of another image and then save them together as a new image. For some reason it does not show up correctly in IE9. It works perfect in FireFox, Chrome and Safari, but in IE9 the only thing that does not work is the rotate tool. Which is set in 15 degree increments and works by dragging the slider either left or right and it rotates the images slightly by 15 degrees depending on the direction you drag it.

Could it not be working because IE9 is not supporting the html5 tag..I am confused.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Consider posting your code, otherwise we won't be able to help you. Cheers

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure which js file to get the code out of to show. Whether it is kineticjs or jquery code? If you can kindly guide me.<form class="form-validate" action="/~mysite/index.php?option=com_editimage&view=submit&Itemid=106" method="post" id="cut" name="cut" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<style>
<div id="buttons">
<div style="clear: both; "/>
<div style="clear: both; "/>
<div style="text-align: center; margin: 10px; ">
<input type="range" id="rotate" value="0" min="-45" max="45" step="1"/>
<br/>
Rotate
</div>

Comment: IE9 supports HTML5. where is your code?

Comment: are you using degree rotation or radian rotation? Basically, what is the function you are using for rotation? consider updating to the newest kineticJS to resolve issues.